# Visual Studio Debugger Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I'm debugging in Visual Studio, I set a breakpoint where I want to start and press F5. When I continue pressing F11 to do a step by step process of how the program runs, when I get to a standard library function e.g std::cout the runs through all the steps in .

Is there anyway I can stop this and allow it to just be more localized? I've had a play with the settings but not stumbled across a way to do it.

I'm completely new to programming so I apologize if this is a simple fix.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two other stepping commands that will likely be helpful to you:

- Step Over (F10) - Steps over a function without going into it.
- Step Out (Shift + F11) - Steps out of the current function.